# I get no ping repsonse to my phone. Why?

Tags: networking

I went to www.whatsmyip.org and got my public IP address for my phone.  Just for kicks and grins, I tried to ping it, but didn't get a reply.  Is ICMP turned off on my android phone?

Comment: Was that the same IP address your phone had locally? If not (which is very highly likely), you're behind NAT and won't get unsolicited packets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either your phone silently drops pings, or the router it's behind, either your wifi router, or the 3G network's router that NATs your phone drops them.

Comment: It is very likely that the provider's network and the phone's configuration itself both block incoming connections of any sort, except any that the provider specifically wants open. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your phone can have a lot of different IP's on different interfaces but that one is not yours. It's internet gateway of your mobile operator.

If I'm wrong consider the point of describing to customers why they should pay for some pings or face the hell of ICMP incapsulation of freebies masters.

Comment: Not entirely sure what this answer is saying, but it seems to have originated from a very naive idea of what IP addresses are and how they are assigned and used.